# Report footer is not exported to Excel

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am using SQL Server Reporting Services 2008 for reporting. When we export the report to Excel, the footer image or textbox is not exported. Header image *is* getting exported successfully.

Does anybody know a solution for this?

Answer (score 12):

Jon is correct they are exported but on opening the file you wont automatically see them as they are not displayed in "Normal" view, in 2007 switch to "Page Layout" view. not sure what its called in other versions of excel.

Note: You also might want to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4944277/rdlc-to-excel-export-header-and-footer-character-limit) as it relates to the use of Headers/Footers in RDLC and exporting them to Excel.

Answer (score 11):

Footers in Reporting Services are exported in Excel.

To see them, you need to click **View** -> **Headers and Footers**  (in Excel)