# SSRS Footer not exporting to excel

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SSRS report footer not export to excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1062199/ssrs-report-footer-not-export-to-excel)

`="Report generatedBy: " & User!UserID.Substring(User!UserID.LastIndexOf("\")+1)`

I have the above code in a text box in report footer in my SSRS 2008 report. I get all the data and header exported to Excel but the footer is not getting exported.

I checked the print preview where I can just see the label with the value `Report generatedBy:` but no other data.

I have checked the preview mode and I can see the **Report generatedBy** correctly with its value.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: I am able to see the footer in print preview...but not getting the value..I just see ReportGeneratedBy:           ...with out any value..is there any thing I am missing to get the value exported..?

Comment: Can you see the value if you view the report as a Word document or a PDF?

Comment: Yes I can see the value in word and PDF

Comment: Maybe it's an Excel bug then? Is the value hiding in a tiny cell or a merged cell somewhere (i.e., if you search the sheet for the UserID, does Excel find it)?

Comment: No I couldn't find any in excel for UserID or Report Generated By.